# OpenMPI on MacOS: Unexpected IP

Tags: macos, ip, openmpi

I installed OpenMPI on MacOS (to test my program before submitting it to a supercomputer) using

```
brew install openmpi
```

However my program failed with the following error:

```
Open MPI detected an inbound MPI TCP connection request from a peer
that appears to be part of this MPI job (i.e., it identified itself as
part of this Open MPI job), but it is from an IP address that is
unexpected.  This is highly unusual.

The inbound connection has been dropped, and the peer should simply
try again with a different IP interface (i.e., the job should
hopefully be able to continue).

  Local host:          MBP-182
  Local PID:           23814
  Peer hostname:       MBP-182 ([[55020,1],0])
  Source IP of socket: 2001:16b8:1033:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:eb52
  Known IPs of peer:
    2001:16b8:1033:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:29b1
```

Why is my own IPv6 address not well-known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacOs generates a temporary IPv6 address for privacy reasons. In `Settings -> Network -> Advanced -> TCP/IP -> Configure IPv6` choose `Manually` and put in the IPv6 address that is given (in the error message) under `Known IPs of peer`.

After that everything should work as intended.